# How to split on second last slash?

Tags: python

I want to split a string on the second last slash,

so if I have a string like `/tmp/fold/merge/annots` I want to get `/tmp/fold/` and `merge/annots` returned.

Same if I have `/tmp/long/dir/fold/merge/annots` I want to get `/tmp/long/dir/fold/` and `merge/annots`

What's the best way to do this? I've tried `rsplit` and `split` a few times but not getting what I want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String splitting works, but I would actually use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this.

```py
import pathlib

p = pathlib.Path('/tmp/long/dir/fold/merge/annots')
p.parts[-2:]
# ('merge', 'annots')
```

If you need it as a path object,

```py
result = pathlib.Path(*p.parts[-2:])
```

which can be converted directly to string if you need to use it that way specifically.

Comment: interesting. I'll try giving that a try too :)

Comment: Path objects are useful especially if you have to do any actual filesystem operations. `with (p / 'some_file.tmp').open('w') as f: f.write('arbitrary data')` for instance, or if you have to find all the .txt files under `p`: `p.rglob('*.txt')`

Comment: would this work with `fold/merge/annots`? Just need to get the `merge/annots` to always appear

Comment: yes `p.parts[-2:]` grabs the last two path elements no matter how many there are. If there are less than two, it will get you as many as there are.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```py
l = '/tmp/fold/merge/annots'

latter = l.split('/',3)[-1]
former = l.replace(latter,'')

print(former)
```

Comment: nice! thank you :)

Comment: what does the `[-1]` do btw? I notice `l.split('/',3)` alone keeps all splits, does `-1` just take the last option then?

Comment: it takes the last element from the list. print out the entire list that `l.split('/',3)` produces. The last element in that list is the one you want. -2 would get the second last and so forth. that's how indexing in python works. -index means indexing in reverse.

Comment: This will fail if there are more than four path segments. You should use `rsplit` instead and count from the right. `l.rsplit('/', 2)[1:].join('/')` for a naive solution.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) I come from a C# background so just getting used to the concept!

Answer (score 0):

To split a string on the penultimate bar, try writing like this:

```
import pathlib

x = pathlib.Path('/tmp/long/dir/fold/merge/annots')
x.parts[-2:]
```